# rgb adds up to black instead of white

Tags: software-recommendation, drawing-tablet, painting

i have an app called sketchbook pro on android..when i try to blend colors it adds up to dark murky black brown..Which is opposite to white.

I want to know why i am getting black, and what can  i do.

**Side Stuff:** 
Also, opacity doesn't work. Opacity works as flow..instead of opacity. And opacity affects each repeating circle instead of whole line in brush setting.

Is there  a better app for painting and drawing.

Comment: Are you sure it's using RGB and **not**  CMYK? CMYK is a subtractive color model and will turn to black.

Comment: there are options to select color...but i think it only  switches color palate and not actual model..i have been  thinking that too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sketchbook simulates painting on a canvas, the same way **all** painting applications do. You are not painting with light therefore the more you paint, the darker things get -- just like on a real life canvas. It is only light which is used to *show you* what you are painting.

Comment: now come to think of it this is true...so is there an app you know that uses rgb model. Or you think it's a bad idea.

Comment: Well, you'd have to look for apps that were like "Litebright" apps. You'd be painting in reverse basically.

Comment: i found out if i use lighten brush mode it works as if i am using additive model.

Comment: Any of the "Dodge" modes in Photoshop will also result in more of a "reverse painting" effect.